# FullCalendar fetching JSON shows different results between browsers

Tags: json, cross-domain, fullcalendar

I am using FullCalendar to show some events. Basically I have a valid json feed at the following url : http://umhelp.info/calendar/jsonreformat.php?regions=int and I want to show events from it on the following calendar : http://umhelp.info/calendar/index.html

On the following browsers it works fine :
Opera
Chrome

On these browsers it loads events only partially :
Firefox
IE

Results between Opera and Chrome are identical, results on Firefox and IE are also identical, so there is definately something very special that does work on browsers in the first group, and does not work in the browsers from the second group.

I already checked that output from the json on Firefox and Opera is the same using this tool : http://www.textdiff.com/ ,so it is not a problem with an actual json feed. I also made sure that the json feed is consistent with the data in the actual calendar system from where it is retrieved (a call to external server which retrieves a different json feed and then reforts it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It had to do with the kind of date the script expects.
It seems to want the date in ISO 8601 and falls back to the browser
implementation of Date if that does not work in case of Firefox.

Probably the browser implementations differ for the built in Date
and chrome etc are a bit smarter parsing it.

Replace the JSON formatter file to accomodate for the date format.